# Same computer shows different IPs on various services

Tags: ip, pbx

I have a simple PBX running on a computer in an office behind a router.
When PBX registers its SIP trunk, service provider is showing IP: 
213.XXX.XXX.XXX
Same IP is shown when a noip2 client is pushing my IP to NO-IP service.

But, when I try to see my IP myself, using online services, like:
http://www.hashemian.com/whoami/
or
curl whoami.io
I get 149.XXX.XXX.XXX

I have no proxies enabled.

1) what could be the reason?
2) is there an online service that can show what my IP is not on port 80 (all those services are constantly showing the 149.XXX.XXX.XXX variant), so I could discuss the results with ISP?

Comment: Couldn't it be that 149.xxx is just your public IP assigned for your internet connection and the 213.xxx public IP is used for the PBX connection?

Comment: Not really, because no special setup was performed for something like this. PBX should work on the IP given to it. But, moreover - the noip client - that has nothing to do with the PBX showing the 213.xxx IP as well

Comment: Trace-route both IPs and you will see the difference, may be your ISP is using some kind of transparent proxy for web.